# how to use custom directive to add other angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs, tooltip

I am a angularjs newbie, and I must miss something simple.
What I am trying to do is to create tooltip by using angular ui. I create a customer directive, in which it will add 3 angular directives to the attribute of the element based on the placeholder value:

```
myApp.directive('ngTooltip', function () { 
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            attrs.$set('tooltip', attrs['placeholder']);
            attrs.$set('tooltip-placement', 'bottom');
            attrs.$set('tooltip-trigger', 'focus');
        }
    }
});
```

In my markup, I have

and it got rendered as expected:

```
<input name="test" placeholder="this is test" tooltip="this is test" tooltip-placement="bottom" tooltip-trigger="focuse" />
```

However, the tooltip does not work.  If I directly apply the 3 tooltip attributes to the markup, the tooltip works.

Looks like the 3 directives added by the custom directive do not get evaluated by angularjs.

Any ideas?

Comment: don't know why my code get cut:

Comment: In my markup, I have 
    <input name="test" placeholder="this is test" ng-tooltip="" />

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15379108/add-directive-from-inside-another-directive-in-angularjs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't dynamically add directives without recompiling the element with `$compile`, which will cause an infinite loop unless you resort to some workaround.  There is an easier way to take care of this: declare a directive template and AngularJS will handle the directives properly.

```
myApp.directive('ngTooltip', function () { 
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<input tooltip tooltip-placement="bottom" tooltip-trigger="focus">',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          attrs.$set('tooltip', attrs['placeholder']);
        }
    }
});
```

Working example: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/b5LHPZX6odZhep8PUdd5?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Hower your code generate a js error: Error: type property can't be changed.  The plunker example does not linked to this sample.  ANy idea?

Comment: Weird, the plunker link still works for me. I create another link, see if it works http://plnkr.co/edit/f5zsNAdVc6hTy3DzmOVN?p=preview.